# GraphicsComplex dynamic colors

Tags: graphics3d, dynamic, color

I have a fairly large `GraphicsComplex` (surface mesh with more than several thousand vertices) and I want to visualize a scalar function that is defined on the vertices. I map the function to vertex colors and use the option `VertexColors` to set the colors when building the `GraphicsComplex`. However, the function changes dynamically and I would like to update the vertex colors without having to rebuild the full `GraphicsComplex` or the `Graphics3D` to visualize it.
In the code below, everything is rebuild and the update is too slow for a dynamic visualization. I would like something that is much faster, e.g. 30 fps. Is this possible?

```
mesh = ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "Cow"}, "MeshRegion"];
vertices = MeshCoordinates[mesh]; 
faces =  MeshCells[mesh, 2];

Manipulate[

 RandomSeed[seed];
 colors = RandomColor[Length[vertices]];
 renderMesh  = GraphicsComplex[vertices, faces, VertexColors -> colors];

 Graphics3D[renderMesh],

 {seed, 1, 1000, 1}
 ]
```

Comment: `VertexColors -> Dynamic@colorfn[seed]` works in V9, but not in V10 or V11.  (Seems like a bug, therefore).

Comment: @MichaelE2 It seems that it does work for `Graphics` but not for `Graphics3D`. Have you reported it?

Comment: @Kuba Yes, [CASE:3872340], but as it's been the weekend, I don't expect a response for a little while yet.

Comment: @MichaelE2 ok thanks, let's see what they say.

Comment: @Kuba Sending an MWE doesn't seem to work.  I used an icosahedron, and the response was, "You don't need Dynamic. Manipulate works fine without it." I wrote back.

Comment: @MichaelE2 :-D yep, one really has to anticipate the answer and be one step ahead, haven't you learned that? :)

Comment: @Kuba The new response: WRI is "working to fix the problem."